# 'to spoil s.b.' - is there a noun for it?

Tags: word-request

Is there a noun for 'to spoil'?
The classical EN dictionaries OED, OALD, CALD, ... seem not to have one listed.

EXAMPLE:
**In the beginning it was a spoil of the most ecstatic and euphoric experiences...**

The phrase ought to express that it was a joyful and pleasant experience of ecstasy and euphoria.

What I'm looking for is a noun for 'to be spoilt'. A synonym for 'a spoiling experience'.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked for here.  I don't know why you think there are "nouns for verbs".  What is the noun for "to eat" or "to play"? I don't know why "spoil" should mean "joyful and pleasant", as the verb "spoil" means "become bad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm going on what has been said in comments on the question and on Jason's answer, but I think you might be looking for something like ***treat***. Trying to work that into your example with correct and idiomatic grammar, you might get:

> In the beginning, it was a **treat**, with the most ecstatic and euphoric experiences.

Actually, using *of* as in your example, just replacing *spoil* with *treat*, isn't wrong. It's just not idiomatic any more. You might also use ***delight***, or ***feast*** - the latter in a metaphorical sense:

> In the beginning, it was a **feast** of the most ecstatic and euphoric experiences.

That conveys the idea that the experiences were provided in great quantity, with the person able to take and enjoy as much of them as they chose.

Comment: +1 for *feast*. Assuming that's what's actually being looked for here ...

Comment: If the OP can clarify what they want more, one of us might edit the question to clarify, even if they can't express it clearly.

Comment: *Overindulgence* and *guilty pleasure* could both work too. What's interesting is that this question reveals something more complex than at first glance.

Comment: @JasonBassford It is an interesting aspect of answering questions for people who are learning English, but they have to ask them in English - it's far from unusual for questions to be more complex than they seem, isn't it? Sometimes questions that just seem to show an utter lack of understanding are quite deep things expressed badly.

Comment: @SamBC - that nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, I had been going to answer the question this way:

In your specific sentence, the noun version of the verb *spoil* is [**spoiler**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoiler).

> **1 a** : one that spoils

So, in your sentence, you would use this:

> In the beginning, it was a **spoiler** of the most ecstatic and euphoric experiences...

This simply adds *er* to the base form of the verb, giving the noun of somebody or something that performs the action described by the verb.

---

However, that's not what you want. I believe you're confusing the meaning of the verb *spoil* with what it actually means in this context:

> The parents spoiled their child *with* dessert.

While this *does* imply that the parents gave their child dessert (but note the use of the verb now, instead of the noun, and *with* rather than *of*), it also means that something negative happened—in this case, the child's appetite for *dinner* was spoiled.

Colloquially, people do say *I'm going to spoil you (rotten).* But they seldom literally mean that they are going to keep providing something that eventually does end up negatively affecting the person (making them rotten). When somebody say *I'm going to spoil you with gifts*, what they really mean is, *I'm going to give you an excessive number of gifts*.

Since *I'm going to spoil you (rotten)* and *I'm going to spoil you (with something)* are idioms, you can't really use the single word *spoil* from those expressions in your own sentence and have it mean the same thing.

In theory, you could say:

> In the beginning, it served as such a distraction that it spoiled their financial health with the most ecstatic and euphoric experiences, preventing them from even thinking about going to work.

But note how that changes the meaning of what I think you want to express.

---

Based on the description given at the end of your question, what I believe you're actually looking for is the noun form of a verb that means the *opposite* of spoil:

> In the beginning, it was an **enabler** of the most ecstatic and euphoric experiences...

Now we have a noun form, and the sentence only has a *positive* sense (discounting the initial *in the beginning*, which implies that it stopped at some point).

Comment: Thanks Jason. Interesting answer. Instead of 'enabler' I am looking for a synonym for 'it was as welcome and spoiling experience' (the 'positive connotation of spoiling here).

Comment: @johann_ka What I'm saying is that there *is* no positive connotation of the word *spoil*. The word, alone, is negative. It's only with the idiom that you get a positive interpretation.

Comment: @johann_ka: Okay, I think I know what you're getting at, thanks to your comment here.

Answer (score -3):

The meaning of `spoil` which you are searching is listed in the `NOUN` section in [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoil).

`Spoil` itself is a noun here, which means along the lines of `booty`, `takings` and `ill-gotten gains`.

Comment: The question is not asking for the meaning of “spoil”, which is probably why you’re getting some downvotes.